# Baking in cakePHP 2 in windows 7

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I am new to the cakePHP and first starting to bake so I face this problem when following a tutorial and do the following:

1. Add paths to php and cakePHP
2. Run the CMD and type "cake" and get the following message:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.2.3 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : C:
Path: C:\
---------------------------------------------------------------
Current Paths:

 -app: C:
 -working: C:
 -root: C:
 -core: C:\xampp\cake\lib

Changing Paths:

Your working path should be the same as your application path to change your pat
h use the '-app' param.
Example: -app relative/path/to/myapp or -app /absolute/path/to/myapp

Available Shells:

[CORE] acl, api, bake, command_list, console, i18n, schema, test, testsuite, upg
rade

To run an app or core command, type cake shell_name [args]
To run a plugin command, type cake Plugin.shell_name [args]
To get help on a specific command, type cake shell_name --help
```

3.I type in the path where the app that's being developed is saved, that is:

```
C:\xampp\htcdocs\blog
```

I have tried to add all possible paths like 
C:...blog\app, 
C:...blog\app\console, 
C:...blog\lib\cake\console,
but I still get the message that the system cannot find the path specified.

I have been looking for the solution for couple of hours now and could only find it for the previous versions of cakePHP or any other OS but Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want  to set your path to folder/app/console of your project. Also to the folder where php.exe resides.  This is the way i've set mine and works for me.

Try typing cake help in cmd, it should show cake help file.

edit: i have change this answer so everyone can have cake configured ok!

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\app>set PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Sh
ared\Windows Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\win
dows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Pr
ogram Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\app\Console;C:\xampp\php;
```

then from your "project" folder (in my case "proyecto") go to app in a cmd window and type "cake help" it should show something like:

Welcome to CakePHP v2.2.1 Console

---

App : app
Path: C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\app\

---

Current Paths:

-app: app

-working: C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\app

-root: C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto

-core: C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\lib

wich means, everything is good to go!

Comment: Do you mean add a path to cake/console of the project to the environment variable?

Comment: well, yes i did, but was not successful

Comment: ok let me show you my path variable:
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\app\Console;C:\xampp\php;

Comment: Proyecto is my project folder, see how i go to Console folder in my path variable, then i have xampp php also added... if you type from a cmd window, sitting in your app directory of your project "cake help" it should show you something like

Current Paths:

 -app: app
 -working: C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\app
 -root: C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto
 -core: C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\lib

which will be good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

1. start the command promt
2. type cd\ press enter and then cd:/xampp/php press enter
3. php.exe C:/xampp/htdocs/cakeblog/lib/cake/console/cake.php bake press enter
   where “C:/xampp/htdocs/cakeblog/lib/cake/console/cake.php” is the path of bake      file.

Have Baking!